# Create count of variable values as table using base R

Tags: r

I am trying to get a frequency table using just base R (because my version does not support magrittr). I tried a few things, but nothing was what I needed. Any ideas?

```
data<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),  b=c(9,9,9),  c=c(12,3,4)  )

#table(data)
#prop.table(data)
```

Goal

```
   1  2  3  4  9  12
a  1  1  1  0  0  0
b  0  0  0  0  3  0
c  0  0  1  1  0  1
```

Comment: How would you have used magrittr here, do you think?

Comment: magrittr is a dependency for the Hmisc package which is what I initially tried using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or completely in base-R:

```
    #edit colnames to work with base reshape
    colnames(data) <- paste0("obs.",colnames(data))
    m_data <- reshape(data,direction="long", varying=1:3)

> with(m_data, table(time, obs))
    obs
time 1 2 3 4 9 12
   a 1 1 1 0 0  0
   b 0 0 0 0 3  0
   c 0 0 1 1 0  1
```

Comment: Nice! I'm still base-reshape illiterate.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @Frank I prefer reshape2 but OP asked for Base R, so I did not want to introduce a new dependency.

Comment: @Heroka Fair enough. I went off of their reason for saying base R (no magrittr) and figured reshape2 was still an option. Guess I was wrong.

Comment: I don't think it's wrong, we just interpreted it differently.

Comment: @Frank It happens, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the data to long format before `table`-ing:

```
library(reshape2)
table(melt(data))

#         value
# variable 1 2 3 4 9 12
#        a 1 1 1 0 0  0
#        b 0 0 0 0 3  0
#        c 0 0 1 1 0  1
```

`library(reshape2)` should be available on CRAN going back many R versions.